# Не могу понять почему знак вопроса в url, LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет.
Заранее благодарен за ответы.
Не могу понять почему знак вопроса в url
.ru/category?/odegda/zhenskaya
параметров никаких нет!

Роут:

```
Route::get('/category', 'CategoryController@index')->name('category.index');
```

блэйд:

```
@foreach($arr_breadcrumbs as $v)
    <li>
        <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="{{$v['name']}}">
            <meta itemprop="url" content="{{ route('category.index', $v['url']) }}">
         </div>
         <a title="{{ $v['name'] }}" href="{{ route('category.index', $v['url'] ) }}">{{$v['name']}}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

если сделать так, то знак вопроса пропадает.

```
{{ route('category.index').$v['url'] }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функцию **route** вторым аргументом передаются параметры, поэтому появляется знак «?».

Подробно описано в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes).